# How to use macros within functions in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I am trying to calculate a hash for each task in airflow, using a combination of dag_id, task_id & execution_date. I am doing the calculation in the **init** of a custom operator, so that I could use it to calculate a unique retry_delay for each task (I don't want to use exponential backoff)

I find it difficult to use the {{ execution_date}} macro inside a call to hash function or int function, in those cases airflow does not replace it the specific date (just keeps the string {{execution_date}} and I get the same has for all execution dates

```
self.task_hash = int(hashlib.sha1("{}#{}#{}".format(self.dag_id,
                                                    self.task_id,
                                                    '{{execution_date}}')
                                       .encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16)
```

I have put task_hash in template_fields, also I have tried to do the calculation in a custom macro - this works for the hash part, but when I put it inside int(), it's the same issue

Any workround, or perhaps I could retrieve the execution_date (on the init of an operator), not from macros?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
self.task_hash = int(hashlib.sha1("{}#{}#{{execution_date}}".format(
    self.dag_id, self.task_id).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16)
```